# How can I make the system notification which is displayed by Jetpack Compose Media3 Media Library Service to take user to my app when user taps on it?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-media3

I have implemented a class `MyMusicSessionService` which derives from `MediaLibraryService()`. Everything works ok and when my app is using the service to start a playback of an audio file, the default system notification is created. So, user can switch to other apps and the playback continues without problem. Even more, the user is able to use the standard playback controls that the default system notification is built with in order to control the playback, such as Play, Pause, Change Position e.t.c

On top of all these, what I want is to allow the user to just tap on the notification and return back to my application, i.e. the system should bring my application to the foreground. Currently, when user taps on the notification, nothing happens.

Do you know how can I do that?